# Angular - How to prevent <a href="#"> on the Nav header dropdown from redirecting to Home Page

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular-13 project, when a user successfully logs in he's redirected to the dashboard. Then on the dashboard Nav header the user can signout:

header.component.ts:

```
signOut() {
 this.router.navigate(['/auth'])
}
```

header.component.html:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown user-menu">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img src="assets/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
    <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Alexander Pierce</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
    <!-- User image -->
    <li class="user-header bg-primary">
      <img src="assets/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
    </li>
    <!-- Menu Footer-->
    <li class="user-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger btn-flat float-right" (click)="signOut()">Sign out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I expect that when I click on **nav-item dropdown user-menu**, it should dropdown and display signout. Then the user should be able to signout.

Instead of the it redirects to the home page.

When I changed # to javascript: void(0);   the dropdown did not respond.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: This may be a silly suggestion, but it made the difference for me way back in angularjs - omit the value on the anchor link, `<a href (click)="something()">...`

Comment: just delete `href`

Comment: @Andres2142 - I removed href and it's not clickable anymore.  <a href (click)="something()">  is not solving the problem either

Comment: Why don't you use routerLink in an anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the same page again you can use period instead of #,

```html
 <a href="." class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
```